# good jquery exention for on-the-fly CRUD

Tags: javascript, jquery, crud

I have a user profile page, and I'd like to have an extension that will let the user edit his details on the page, on the fly.

The way I figure this happening is once any value is clicked (i.e., "my nickname") it is converted to an editable `textarea`, and on blur of said `textarea`, the data is submitted via ajax to the sever, and the form will be converted back to plaintext, with the updated data.

Has anyone heard of an extention that does this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is often referred to as inline editing.
Here is an example: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html